# Sort array with strings with leading numeric expressions of parent-child relationships

Tags: php, sorting, parent-child, numeric, natural-sort

I have a flat array containing numeric hierarchical prefixes before textual strings.  I need to naturally sort the strings so that each "section" and "subsection" is logically ordered.

```
$array = [
    '9.8. Session',
    '9.5. Date & Time',
    '2. Two',
    '9. Built-in Functions',
    '9.10. Other',
    '3. Three',
    '9.1. String',
    '9.9. Directory',
    '1. One',
    '9.2. Arithmetic',
    '9.7. Database',
    '9.3. Variable',
    '9.6. Object',
    '9.4. Array',
];
```

I've tried to sort with `sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)` and `sort($array, SORT_STRING)` but I'm not able to get the desired result. Specifically, it is imperative that `9.` (parent section) comes before `9.1.` (child section) and that `9.10.` comes after `9.2.`.

Desired result:

```
[
    '1. One',
    '2. Two',
    '3. Three',
    '9. Built-in Functions',
    '9.1. String',
    '9.2. Arithmetic',
    '9.3. Variable',
    '9.4. Array',
    '9.5. Date & Time',
    '9.6. Object',
    '9.7. Database',
    '9.8. Session',
    '9.9. Directory',
    '9.10. Other'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_multisort()` will be more direct and efficient versus making 2x function calls within the *n log n* time complexity of `usort()`.

Generate an array of values consisting of only the leading substring before the first space.  The remainder of each string (after the first space) is assumed to be irrelevant and can be ignored while sorting.

The modified array will properly order sections and subsections as desired.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3Y1Ld))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => strtok($v, ' '),
        $array
    ),
    SORT_NATURAL,
    $array
);
```

This approach is robust enough to support deeper chilren/subsections as well. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/i1oXW))

---

Alternatively, by removing ONLY the final `.` from each numeric expression, the above technique can be refined to avoid iterated function calls and is likely to perform a little better. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z6N5S))

```
array_multisort(
    str_replace('. ', ' ', $array),
    SORT_NATURAL,
    $array
);
```

This also proves itself to be successful when dealing with deeper parent-child relationships. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NMEeR))

Answer (score -1):

You can Create your own Sorting with the "usort" function 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php